# Jquery assign value to input

Tags: jquery, input

I have the following input field

`<input type="text" name="location[state_id]"  id="location[state_id]" value=""  >`

and i am trying to assign there a value with the following jquery

```
$("#location\\[state_id\\]").val("5");
```

but it does not working! It works only if the name of both is only location.

Thanks

Comment: You cod is working for me see http://jsfiddle.net/zg4Mf/. is your JavaScript code inside $(document).ready?

Answer (score 26):

As `#` is an id selector, you could try to set the id of the input to a valid CSS id and let the name of the input the same (I assume that this format is required by a framework of some kind). For example, the HTML can look like:

```
<input type="text" id="location_state_id" name="location[state_id]" value="" />
```

and the jQuery expression:

```
$('#location_state_id').val('5');
```

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="location[state_id]"class="input" id="location[state_id]" value="" >

$(".input").val("5");
```

or

you can use curt's answer:

`$("input[name='location[state_id]'").val("5");`

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to use the `name` as part of the selector, you can use the following selector:

```
$("input[name='location[state_id]'").val("5");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjwJC/)

Answer (score 2):

### JQuery

```
$('input[name="location[state_id]"]').val(5);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how may i write it, because i have inside php $var='{jquery code}' with single quotes.